# What is a good LaTeX editor for brainstorming?

Tags: editors

Short Background: I enjoy using MS word when drafting and doing research. The ability to manipulate objects like matrices and series is extremely fast as I see them as I would write them, and yet I can tweak terms with ease, use copy and paste on pieces of an object, disect at the object level and move components around, etc....

Additionally, I can seemlessly write in MathML in the same frame as I'm manipulation objects. (So instead of editing a TeX file or ML File and then looking at the compiled output, I can in the output file itself, write MathML and have it autocompile there itself (no time wasted switching frames or coordinating place in code with location of object)

Whats a LaTeX editor that supports this?

BakomaTeX, gets an honorable mention as it supports object level manipulation, but the production of these objects needs to happen in the separate code (or via their drop down menus) and can't be done inline.

Is there a LaTeX editor that combines real time inLine equation compilation and  object level manipulation in one frame?

---

I guess technically nothing stops me from secretly using MS Word to think, and then quietly (but a little painfully) switching to LaTeX when another human will be involved.

But It would be nice if the language I present and publish in, was the same that I worked in.

Comment: No. Use pen and paper.

Comment: Research work and presentation work are different things.

Comment: Pen and paper is inefficient if I need to repeatedly instantiate multiple copies of a complicated looking object and tweak parameters. Example suppose I have a procedure (take a  5x5 matrix, do a human touch to it, then feed ti a program, get a copy back, duplicate, then again affect the result slightly repeat...) doing that in pen and paper is tedious, there's a lot of Re-writing and re-writing that would happen. In more abstract areas thats not a problem, but in my particular interests this unfortunately arises.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the issue  if Bakoma is not a good alternative (and because I am a MS Word ignorant)  but ... you know LyX ?

Comment: Maybe also have a look at TeXStudio with its preview and other assistants? (Second thing mentioned here: https://youtu.be/wxRogM4GmFQ)

Comment: To extend my earlier comment: What you want to do and seek is something LaTeX is not supposed to do. LaTeX is for presenting your final thoughts of your research, not for brainstorming. LaTeX expects a syntax that needs to know you finished what you wanted to write. As you are satisfied with Word, just keep on using it.